# Re-using a class as a variable in C#

Tags: c#

I have a reference at the top of my class like so :

```
using my.super.long.name.space.that.i.want.to.shorten;
```

Inside this namespace I want to access some classes, so for ease of use I would do the following :

```
using easier = my.super.long.name.space.that.i.want.to.shorten;
```

But then I need to access some classes within this like so :

```
easier.i.need.this.class.please myclass = ...
```

I need to use this across multiple classes so I would like to have a class of my own that contains this. Something similar to this :

```
public class getClasses{
   public static class1 = easier.i.need.this.class.please
   public static class2 = easier.i.need.this.class.thankyou
}
```

So then I could just do :

```
getClasses.class2 myClass2 = ....
```

Is this possible ?

This is heavily exaggerated to express the problem Id like to solve.

EDIT

Okay, here's a super simple explanation. I have a class located at

```
mynamespace.myClass
```

And I wish to reuse this across multiple files my using a single word variable, rather than call `mynamespace.myClass`. Something like this :

```
mynamespaceClassRef myObj = ...
```

Where `mynamespaceClassRef` = `mynamespace.myClass`

Comment: This sounds more like you've got a class hierarchy problem. Why have you go such long nested names?

Comment: @Enigmativity im using a prebuilt dll i have no control over -.- the one i have is 7 levels deep, the question is slightly exaggerated. You are definitely correct though, but im afraid i cant change anything about it

Comment: It sounds like basically you just need to duplicate the using alias directives in multiple clases. (Note that `using static` can simplify this too. It's hard to give a concrete example with only pseudo-code to work with - if you can provide a concrete example of the problem, we'll be in a better position to provide concrete solutions.)

Comment: Would be a great use for typedef, but unfortunately C# doesn't have that.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/375646) - as @Enigmativity has already said.

Comment: @DaisyShipton - Yes, a [mcve] would be great here.

Comment: @DaisyShipton editted answer, apologies if the previous was a mess.

Comment: The answer is still to just have `using mynamespaceClassRef = mynamespace.myClass` in each file. One note: when writing examples, it's helpful to follow the normal naming convention for the platform, otherwise it can provide unnecessary distractions.

Comment: both points taken. it cannot be done then

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a class to specify the shorter aliases for classes, but it seems you have a namespace complexity problem.

If you want to go with this, you could use:

```
using Task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task;
using StringTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>;
```

You can't make 'sub namespaces' inside your alias, but this should help you out most of the time.

Comment: I don't think so, that is still about namespaces.

Comment: I think this is what im going to end up doing, but id like to use it in multiple files

Comment: Then you have to repeat that over and over again. Not a pretty face.

Comment: The second line is literally `using easier = my.super.long...`, I'm confused why you think it's not the same thing?

Comment: `easier` is the namespace here. OP then needs `easier.ClassName` and wants to prevent that. @DavidG